# Yii2: How to start an export programmatically

Tags: yii2

I have several views with [DynaGrid](http://demos.krajee.com/dynagrid) and [ExportMenu](http://demos.krajee.com/export). I need every day to save all the exports to an archive as CSV files. I do not know, how to start a new export (which is defined in a DynaGrid) from a controller.

I have found the following possible solutions, but none of them is optimal:

- I can define the exports in corresponding models and then realise the exports through actions in controllers, like in [this example](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/56451-programatically-of-export-to-excel-select-all-gridview/page__view__findpost__p__257101). But then I have to define the same export twice and I risk, that there will be differences between the two exports.
- I can use the [Codeception](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-codeception) and e.g. in the frame of an acceptance test to simulate a click on the export menu. This solution is relative easy to implement, but I find it unstable.
- I can also prepare links to the export files, so it will be easier to make the exports with Codeception.

See:

```
<?= echo yii\helpers\Html::a('Export', ['controller/action'], [
    'class'=>'classname',
    'data'=>[
        'method'=>'post',
        'params'=>[
            'export_type'=>'CSV',
            'exportFull_w0' => '1',
            'export_columns' => '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20',
            'column_selector_enabled' => '1'
        ],
    ]
]) ?>
```

Is there something more straightforward?  I need something like the extension [UploadFromUrl](https://github.com/igogo5yo/yii2-upload-from-url), which enables to download files, like this:

```
$url = 'http://static.yiiframework.com/files/logo/yii.png' ;
$path = 'uploads/yii.png';

$file = UploadFromUrl::initWithUrl($url);
$file->saveAs($path);
```

But it does not enable to use post parameters and urls from the current Yii-application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I have used the following solution.

In the Dynagrid set the stream parameter to false:

```
'gridOptions' => [
    ...
    'toolbar' => [
        ...
        \kartik\export\ExportMenu::widget([
            ...
            'stream' => false,
            'folder' => '@webroot/export',
        ]);
    ],
],
```

If the stream is set to false, the exported files are saved in the directory 'folder'.

In the **web** controller define a new action, which will save the export data from the action with Dynagrid:

```
public function actionExport()
{
    $_POST['export_type'] = 'CSV';
    $_POST['exportFull_w0'] = '1';
    $_POST['export_columns'] = '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15';
    $_POST['column_selector_enabled'] = '1';

    Yii::$app->runAction('controller/data');

    return true;
}
```

The action 'export' can be started from **console** through cURL, as described in the following answer: [Yii2: Run a web action in a console controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601653/yii2-run-a-web-action-in-a-console-controller/36646477#36646477)

Answer (score 2):

I've not personally used DynaGrid but I've written a few exports using this lib https://github.com/arogachev/yii2-excel - This way I can customize much of my exports features. You also get to write custom SQL which you can easily change assuming your exports change without affecting DynaGrid. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that you can then run this using a cron job daily. No need to simulate clicks or use codeception.

Comment: This solution is possible, but it would require, that I define all the exports once again. I would like to use the export settings from the Dynagrid to be sure, that the export files will be identical and I do not have to by every change adjust and test two types of exports.