# Yii2: Run a web action in a console controller

Tags: yii2

Is it possible to run a **web** action in a **console** controller?

In a web controller (yii\web\Controller) I have an action which I would like to run as a cron job. But if I try to run it in a console controller (yii\console\Controller):

```
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action');
```

then I receive the following error message:

```
Error: Unknown command "controller/action".
```

Comment: You could simply make a http request (using curl or else). Or put your code elsewhere to be able to use it in a console and a web controller.

Comment: @soju in this particular case is the use of cURL relative difficult, because there is authentication with LDAP credentials.

Comment: Then you should review your code logic.

Comment: There is an extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25355483/how-can-i-call-a-console-command-in-web-application-in-yii-2-0

Comment: You are wrong Robert, this extension is about running console command from web...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I did not understand the context of the question.

As @soju says, you should find a way to do it using CURL, but there is a way.

```
$config = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
            require(Yii::getAlias('@common').'/config/main.php'),
            require(Yii::getAlias('@common').'/config/main-local.php'),
            require(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/config/main.php'),
            require(Yii::getAlias('@frontend').'/config/main-local.php')
        );

$web_application = new \yii\web\Application($config);
$web_application->runAction('/site/index',['param1' => 1,'param2' => 2]);
```

You should be aware that the controller works with their behaviors, then the AccessControl could prevent the execution

Comment: I have tried your solution. It worked, but there were several problems, so I decided to use cURL, see the code below.

Answer (score 3):

Run a web action in a console controller:

```
Yii::$app->controllerNamespace = "app\controllers";
Yii::$app->runAction('controller/action');
```

Assign `controllerNamespace` before running the web action from console.

---

In addition, disable `enableCsrfValidation` for the web action:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{    
    if ($action->id == 'action') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }    

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

> The `'action'` ID could be replaced with your current web action ID.

Comment: where to add it? in console controller or in web controller ?

Comment: @MrFaisal Add the code in console controller for calling web action.

Comment: @MrNick I am talking about `enableCsrfValidation`

Comment: @MrFaisal disabling `enableCsrfValidation` is added into web controller, the `'action'` ID could be replaced with your current web action ID.

Comment: I am wondering why it's not marked as correct answer. It works for me

Comment: @MrNick but I am now facing a problem. If I want to access my index page of same controller via GUI it shows me blank page :|

Comment: @MrFaisal Make sure that `return parent::beforeAction($action);` is always return from `beforeAction()`.

Comment: @MrNick yes I was missing this

Answer (score 1):

The solution with cURL.

In the **web** controller have to be disabled the CSRF validation:

```
public function beforeAction() {
    if ($this->action->id == 'export') {
       Yii::$app->controller->enableCsrfValidation = false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

The cURL commands in the **console** Controller can look e.g. like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_REFERER         => $url,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION   => true,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => 'curl-cookie.txt',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => '/var/www/yii/frontend/web/tmp',
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 120,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 120,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "Dark Secret Ninja/1.0",
    CURLOPT_POST            => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => "LoginForm[username]=".$username.
        "&LoginForm[password]=".$password.
        "&LoginForm[rememberMe]=1",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
);
curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

if ( $httpCode != 200 ){
    echo "Return code is {$httpCode} \n"
        .curl_error($ch);
} else {
    echo htmlspecialchars($response);
}
curl_close($ch);
```