# Yii2- getting errors while calling web controller from console controller

Tags: controller, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, cron-task

I am working on `yii2`. I have a `create` action in my controller named `MeterpingController`.

```
class MeterpingController extends Controller
{
     public function beforeAction($action)
    {

    if ($action->id == 'create') {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);

   }

   public function actionCreate()
   {
      foreach ($record as $item){

        // var_dump($item->MSN);
         $date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $item->PingDateTime);
        if($this->isSaved($item->MSN))
        {
           // return true;
        }
        else if($this->isVerified($item->MSN))
        {
            // return true;
        }
        else if($this->ogpCreated($item->MSN,$date_time))
        {
            $m = new MeterPing;
            $m ->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
            $m->start_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $start_time);
            $m->end_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $end_time);

           $m->meter_msn = $item->MSN;
           $m->meter_id = Meters::msnmapToid($m->meter_msn);
           $m->meter_type = Meters::mType($m->meter_msn);
           $m->sub_div_code = Ogpdetail::msnTosubdiv($item->MSN);
           $m->sub_div_name = Ogpdetail::subDivToName($m->sub_div_code);
           $m->meter_ping_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $item->PingDateTime);
        $m->save();
        }


    }
    return $this->redirect(['index']);
   }
}
```

Below are the two functions

```
 public static function isVerified($msn)
{
    $meter = Installations::find()->where(['meter_msn'=>$msn])->one();

    if($meter)
        return true;
    return false;
}

public static function ogpCreated($msn,$date_time){
    $meter = Ogpdetail::find()->where(['meter_serial' => $msn])->one();

    if($meter)
    {
        if($date_time>$meter['created_at'])
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

I have a console controller in which I am trying to call the above `action`

```
namespace console\controllers;


use yii\console\Controller;
use Yii;

class CronController extends Controller {

public function actionIndex() {
    Yii::$app->controllerNamespace = "backend\controllers";

    Yii::$app->runAction('meterping/create');
}
}
```

In `cmd` I am using the following command

```
E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web>php yii cron
```

The error I am getting is

```
Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\backend\controllers\MeterpingController.php(126): 
backend\controllers\MeterpingController::isVerified('002999001152')
#1 [internal function]: backend\controllers\MeterpingController- 
>actionCreate()
#2 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): 
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction- 
>runWithParams(Array)
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): 
yii\base\Controller->runAction('create', Array)
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module- 
>runAction('meterping/creat...', Array)
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\console\controllers\CronController.php(24): 
yii\console\Application->runAction('meterping/creat...')
#7 [internal function]: console\controllers\CronController->actionIndex()
#8 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): 
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#9 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction- 
>runWithParams(Array)
#10 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(128): yii\base\Controller- 
>runAction('', Array)
#11 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): 
yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#12 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module- 
>runAction('cron', Array)
#13 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(147): 
yii\console\Application->runAction('cron', Array)
#14 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\console\Application- 
>handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#15 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#16 {main}
```

Previously I was calling `echo` directly from `actionIndex()` and using the same command I was able to see the correct result. But calling an `action` from another controller seems not to be working.

**Note:** I want to call it on schedule basis so that's why I have created a cron job.

How can I set my code to not to show this error in `cmd`?

**Update 1**

As per suggestion was given and following this [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/747/write-use-a-custom-component-in-yii2-0)

I have done the following

1. Created a `components` folder under `common` folder.
2. Created a custom component  inside components folder

   ```
    namespace common\components;


    use Yii;
    use yii\base\Component;
    use yii\base\InvalidConfigException;
    use app\models\Installations;
    use app\models\Meters;
    use common\models\MeterPing;
    use common\models\MeterpingSearch;
    use common\models\Ogpdetail;
    use yii\web\Controller;
    use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
    use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls\Style;
    public function create() {

        //...My code   

    }
   ```
3. Registered the component in `common/config/main-local.php`

   ```
    'components' => [

      'pingManager' => [

         'class' => 'common\components\MyComponent',

         ],
       ]
   ```
4. In my web controller I have done the following

   ```
   Yii::$app->pingManager->create();
   return $this->redirect(['index']);
   ```

Now when I try to access it via web it gives me bellow error

```
Unable to find 'common\components\MyComponent' in file: E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\common/components/MyComponent.php. Namespace missing?
```

**Update 2**

I was missing the class name so I updated it to `MyComponent` and access it via web. It did work. Now when I try to run it through console I am getting below error.

```
Exception 'Error' with message 'Class 'app\models\Installations' not found'

in E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\common\components\MyComponent.php:89

Stack trace:
#0 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\common\components\MyComponent.php(65): 
common\components\MyComponent::isVerified('002999001064')
#1 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\backend\controllers\MeterpingController.php(148): 
common\components\MyComponent->create()
#2 [internal function]: backend\controllers\MeterpingController- 
>actionCreate()
#3 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): 
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction- 
>runWithParams(Array)
#5 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): 
yii\base\Controller->runAction('create', Array)
#6 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module- 
>runAction('meterping/creat...', Array)
#7 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\console\controllers\CronController.php(24): 
yii\console\Application->runAction('meterping/creat...')
#8 [internal function]: console\controllers\CronController->actionIndex()
#9 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): 
call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#10 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(156): yii\base\InlineAction- 
>runWithParams(Array)
#11 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Controller.php(128): yii\base\Controller- 
>runAction('', Array)
#12 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(523): 
yii\console\Controller->runAction('', Array)
#13 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(180): yii\base\Module- 
>runAction('cron', Array)
#14 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\Application.php(147): 
yii\console\Application->runAction('cron', Array)
#15 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory- 
web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(380): yii\console\Application- 
>handleRequest(Object(yii\console\Request))
#16 E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\yii(27): yii\base\Application->run()
#17 {main}
```

The `89` number is `$meter = Installations::find()->where(['meter_msn'=>$msn])->one();`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: [May help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601653/yii2-run-a-web-action-in-a-console-controller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: Run a web action in a console controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36601653/yii2-run-a-web-action-in-a-console-controller)

Comment: @Both, I have tried the given solution but it doesn't works for me

Comment: you should assign the `controllerNamespace` before calling the function the given solutions work.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I have updated my question.

Comment: @InsaneSkull check my updated question

Comment: @Bizley I have updated my question kindly check

Comment: Are you sure your `Installations` class in `common` not `backend`? Because your component is in  common and `app` refers to `common, backend or frontend on context`

Comment: @InsaneSkull I am getting `'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Request::post()'` error on line 70 in `MyComponent` and the line 70 is `$m->load(Yii::$app->request->post());`

Comment: There is no `post()` in console, you cannot use that, try to find other way. and I still don't understand what do you wan to achieve in console without user post data. I don't see any usecase here atleast not with post. Still you want to use post, you need to store post data first and then run the action.

Comment: @InsaneSkull I want to use the console for performing scheduler task i.e. I want to run automatically. The process involves the checking of meters. and if the 3rd check `if ($this->ogpCreated($item->MSN, $date_time))` is `true` then it should save the data into the table. So that's why `post` is used.

Comment: And how do you send post data in console?

Comment: @InsaneSkull like this `$m->load(Yii::$app->request->post());`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172473/discussion-between-insane-skull-and-mr-faisal).

Comment: look, you are trying to load the data from the `post` array which isnt anywhere when you are using console, if you are trying to automate the process how do you expect the data to be submitted in `Yii::$app->request->post()` ? even if the process is triggered via job it still needs to send data you , what is the actual process for which you use this action ? what is the work flow , the user fills any form ? and then submits to the action?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam here is my flow. `1. I have an API which gives me data from 3rd party DB`. `2. I perform some checks on the data one by one`. `3. After performing checks I the saved the data into one of my table in my DB`. For now, I am doing this process manually. Like I have created a `view` in my `GUI` and then on a button click all the above flow starts. But all I want is to automate the process. So, I am now confused that how I can save data without using `post` as the `console` don't use post.

Comment: ok tell me when you are free tomorrow, will talk about it in chat just leave a message here.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam bro I am free till 10 AM. after that will be busy in meetings today.

Comment: that's pretty early i guess for a night Owl like me

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam main fer na hi samjhan? :|

Comment: haha, yar i need to check it by implementing at my end as it is not working at your end with the given solution so i would check it when i reach home

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam ok bro. when will you be online from home?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is not the answer you expected, but you should avoid this problem in the first place. If you need to call controller action code from different place, you probably have some design issues in your application. Controllers should be slim and does not contain any advanced logic or reusable code. If you need to call controller action from different place, the this action is probably too fat and you should extract its logic to separate component or helper. So in your case:

Create component and extract action logic into it:

```
class PingManager extends \yii\base\Component {

    public function create($record, $start_time, $end_time, $data) {
        foreach ($record as $item) {
            $date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $item->PingDateTime);
            if ($this->isSaved($item->MSN)) {
                // return true;
            } else {
                if ($this->isVerified($item->MSN)) {
                    // return true;
                } else {
                    if ($this->ogpCreated($item->MSN, $date_time)) {
                        $m = new MeterPing();
                        $m->load($data);
                        $m->start_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $start_time);
                        $m->end_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $end_time);

                        $m->meter_msn = $item->MSN;
                        $m->meter_id = Meters::msnmapToid($m->meter_msn);
                        $m->meter_type = Meters::mType($m->meter_msn);
                        $m->sub_div_code = Ogpdetail::msnTosubdiv($item->MSN);
                        $m->sub_div_name = Ogpdetail::subDivToName($m->sub_div_code);
                        $m->meter_ping_date_time = str_replace('T', ' ', $item->PingDateTime);
                        $m->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function isSaved($msn) {
        // todo
    }

    private function isVerified($msn) {
        $meter = Installations::find()->where(['meter_msn' => $msn])->one();
        if ($meter) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private function ogpCreated($msn, $date_time) {
        $meter = Ogpdetail::find()->where(['meter_serial' => $msn])->one();
        if ($meter) {
            return $date_time > $meter['created_at'];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Register component in app configuration:

```
'components' => [
    'pingManager' => [
        'class' => PingManager::class,
    ],
    // ...
],
```

Use it in your console controller:

```
class CronController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        // initialize $record, $start_time, $end_time, $data

        Yii::$app->pingManager->create($record, $start_time, $end_time, $data);
    }
}
```

And in web controller:

```
class MeterpingController extends Controller {

    public function beforeAction($action) {
        if ($action->id == 'create') {
            $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        }

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function actionCreate() {
        // initialize $record, $start_time, $end_time

        Yii::$app->pingManager->create($record, $start_time, $end_time, Yii::$app->request->post());
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
}
```

Comment: According to your update, you did not created `MyComponent` class, only method under `common\components` namespace.

Comment: so I had to change the `MyComponent` to `PingManager`?

Comment: I am getting `'Calling unknown method: yii\console\Request::post()'` error on line 70 in `MyComponent` and the line 70 is `$m->load(Yii::$app->request->post());`

Comment: See my update - there is no POST data in console application, so you need to pass required data to component.

Comment: so I have to initialize the `$data = " "` in the console controller?

Comment: You need to initialize `$data` with data which can be used by `MeterPing::load()`. String with one space may not be the best idea.

Comment: So you mean to say i have to do this `$data=Yii::$app->request->post();` ?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what you're trying to do, but there is no POST data in console, so you cannot use `Yii::$app->request->post()` in your cron command. If this is your code, you should know what data is required and provide some source of it. Try start with empty array (`$data = []`) or remove `$m->load($data);` - maybe it is unnecessary.

Comment: I want to run a process automatically. So for this, I am using a console app. When the process runs it should save the incoming data from `api` to its database table. So for inserting, I am using `post` in my controller